# Get tuple from list and use it as Map key

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell newbie and I'm trying to get use `Map.fromList`. I have defined the following `data` types:

```
type No = String
data Arco = Arco { de :: No
                 , para :: No
                 , custo :: Float
                 } deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
```

I have a list of `Arco` and I want map them, using the `(de, para)` tuple as the key, and `custo` as the value. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could achieve this using folding functions or list mapping to first convert a list of `Arco` values to a simple list, and then just using `Map.fromList` to build a map from a list of key/value pairs. Something along the lines of (not tested):

```
Map.fromList (foldr (\x res -> ((de x, para x), custo x):res) [] yourArcoList)
```

or with `map`:

```
Map.fromList $ map (\x -> ((de x, para x), custo x)) yourArcoList
```

or with list comprehension:

```
[((de x, para x), custo x) | x <- yourArcoList]
```

`de`, `para`, and `cusot` are functions automatically created by Haskell for you so that you can extract the field values from the type values.

Comment: I liked the `map` solution, it reads out nicely for a beginner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here it is with explicit recursion:

```
type No = String
data Arco = Arco { de :: No
                 , para :: No
                 , custo :: Float
                 } deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

my_func xs = helper xs []
       where helper [] acc = reverse acc
             helper (x:xs) acc = let key = (de x, para x)
                                     val = custo x
                                 in helper xs ( (key, val):acc )



ghci>:l 1.hs

ghci>let a = Arco "hello" "world" 3.0
ghci>let b = Arco "goodbye" "mars" 10.0

ghci>let list = my_func [a, b]
ghci>list
[(("hello","world"),3.0),(("goodbye","mars"),10.0)]

ghci>import qualified Data.Map as M
ghci>let map = M.fromList list
ghci>map
fromList [(("goodbye","mars"),10.0),(("hello","world"),3.0)]
ghci>M.lookup ("hello", "world") map
Just 3.0
```

Comment: One slight nitpick: I wouldn't give the variables the names of the functions in standard library: in this case it's `map`. `mymap` would be a better name.

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev, Thanks...good advice for a beginner in any language.